# Setting statusCallbackEvent on outbound calls with Voice SDK

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

Is there any way to change what events trigger the status callback? Normally you can use `statusCallbackEvent` but I can't seem to find a way to make this work for the Voice SDK's leg of the call. It works fine on the call leg of the outbound participant, but not the Voice SDK's call leg. I only get `completed` status event for this leg (and I also can get `ringing` from the called action url).

Things I tried without success:

- Updating the call using the REST api to set `statusCallbackEvent` to `initiated ringing answered completed` when the outbound call starts
- Setting `statusCallbackEvent` as an outbound parameter on the Voice SDK's token (in PHP you can set custom parameters using `$clientToken->allowClientOutgoing(...)` but it seems normal parameters cannot be modified)

I really wish you could set this on the TwiML Application so that any numbers calling out with that application set will just automatically use your set events. That or let me set the parameters on the client's token.

One way to fix this is just to poll for the information but that is an ugly hack and isn't real time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I don't think you can do what you're asking for here, but for good reason.

When you are placing the call from the Voice SDK, that call leg is then between the application and Twilio. You know the call was "initiated", because you started it. There is no "ringing" because Twilio is not a phone and won't ring. You know it is "answered" because a request is made to your voice URL defined by the TwiML app. And finally, you do get the "completed" event.

As you say, you do get the events for the outbound leg of the call from Twilio to another phone number.

Comment: This is interesting that the action URL the application calls for the Voice SDK outbound call returns the call status as `ringing` so Twilio is for sure tracking this state despite you saying they don't. I'll just make my code set the status to `answered` for these calls when the action url is triggered.

Comment: The leg between your browser and Twilio is different to the leg between Twilio and the outbound number. They have different CallSids and yes, you can get the `ringing` status for the outbound call because it is being sent from Twilio and Twilio is monitoring the status of that call. The call from the browser to Twilio connects (as good as) immediately, so there is no use for a "ringing" status on this inbound leg.